# Installing compiled Python modules on Windows on a virtual env

Tags: windows, python, virtualenv

I'm using `virtualenv` to maintain a Python installation on Windows.

I want to install the popular `PIL` module, which comes as `.exe`. I run the `.exe` installer, but it tries to install to the regular Python folder and it doesn't give me any opportunity to change to the virtual environment.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, just letting it install, then copying the files into the virtual environment?

It appears that you can use the 'Open Archive' option of 7-Zip to open up the exe file.  Why not try opening it up, extracting your files and place them in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the virtualenv, the `easy_install /path/to/exe`

Comment: Is this possible with `pip` too?